# Problem with jquery load function

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page where I use the jquery load function to load data from a php file. The problem is that it does not always return the correct number of results. I have tried receiving the data straight from the php file and that worked perfectly. What could cause this problem with the load function?? It should only return a max of 5 entries.

```
s_showLoader();
$("#s_content").load("sdata.php", {s_page:1, user:fbusername}, s_hideLoader);
```

The show and hide loader functions just show and hide a gif loader. page is the page of pagination to display and user is just used to verify the user is logged in.

UPDATE 1:
Here is example of what the sample return looks like. It is in a while loop and is generated for each entry that is returned.

```
<table border="0">
<tr><td width="500">
  <?php if($s_rows['name']){ echo $s_rows['name']; }else{ echo "User"; } ?><?php echo " | <a id='s_datedata".$s_idnum."'>".$s_rows['date']."</a>"; ?>
  <div class="s_label<?php echo $s_idnum; ?>"><?php echo $s_display; ?></div>
  <br><a href="#" class="s_entry-info" id="<?php echo $s_idnum; ?>">More Info...</a><br>
  <div class="list_con" id="s_condata<?php echo $s_idnum; ?>"><?php echo $s_rows['content']; ?></div>
  <div class="list_tags" id="s_contags<?php echo $s_idnum; ?>"><?php echo $s_rows['tags']; ?></div>
  </td>
  <td width="10" align="right"><!-- delete button if correct user is logged in-->
  <?php

    if($user && ($fbuser == $s_rows['fb_id']) ){
     //show delete button
    ?>

    <a href=""><img src="close-icon.png" title="Click here to delete your listing" class="delopt" id="<?php echo $s_idnum; ?>" onclick="return del_list(<?php echo $s_rows['id']; ?>,<?php echo $s_rows['fb_id']; ?>)" height="25" width="25" alt="delete" border="0"></a>
    <?php
    }else{
       //echo $fbuser."|".$rows['fb_id'];
    }
  ?>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE 2:
This is the only POST variable in the php file. The rest of the data comes from the standard facebook api.

```
 $s_page_num = floor($_POST['s_page']);
```

Comment: Please extend your question with more code. What kind of data is passed from the PHP script to the client and how does this data look?

Comment: Does your PHP script expect POST or GET? Specifying the data set in load() using the `{name:value}` notation is sent as POST, and not GET...Just in case you are unfamiliar with the difference, and just in case it does make a difference in you code...

Comment: it uses POST. There is only one line of POST data shown in the UPDATE 2 of the question

Comment: The PHP code is looking for `$_POST['s_page']`, but you seem to be passing it a variable `page` in the jQuery `load` function.

Comment: That was a typo when asking the question not in the code. I updated the question

Comment: Someone suggested that their might be a difference in the time jquery loads the page content and the time it take the php code to get the data entries. Is there any way to make sure that all the results are returned by php before jquery load outputs results?

Comment: I'd recommend trying [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) as you will have more control and likely arrive at a resolution quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html content instead of load.

```
function Load_Content() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourfilename.php',
                cache: false,
                data: "s_page="+s_page_value,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#s_content").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
```